# How to make theorem title (such as Theorem, lemma, definition, etc) in margin while theorem number as usual.

Tags: theorems, marginpar

How to make the theorem style like:

```
1.1.3. There is a theorem.         Theorem

       it may be several lines.

       The theorem 1.1.3 end.

1.1.1. There is a lemma.           lemma

       The lemma 1.1.1 end.
```

(for oneside documentclass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{marginname}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##2\theorem@separator]\marginpar{\theorem@headerfont ##1}}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]\marginpar{\theorem@headerfont ##1}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{marginname}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{thm}
blah blah
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

It may work better if you use `\marginnote` (from `marginnote` package) instead of `\marginpar`.

Or you can use `amsthm`'s `\newtheoremstyle` (in differnt syntax) to do the trick.